# Unable to connect to database using JDBC driver (JTDS)

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm in need to use a custom program that helps in database migration. It needs to connect to `JTDS JDBC` driver. Unfortunately I receive an error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
```

The program is a batch file and I have already downloaded the driver.
Is there any specific location the path has to be added for the program to work?

Comment: The source database that I'm trying to connect to is "Sybase ASE"

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that when your batch file runs the java command that you're specifying the driver's jar on the classpath argument:

```
java -classpath /path/to/your/driver.jar ...
```